# VueJS PDF Converter

Tags: javascript, pdf, vuejs2, html-to-pdf

The issue I am having is I want to convert my Vue HTML in to a pdf and download it for user. I have tried using [JSPDF](http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/)

but it downloads an empty page. It does download when I pass only text to it.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

// All units are in the set measurement for the document
// This can be changed to "pt" (points), "mm" (Default), "cm", "in"
setTimeout(function () {
doc.fromHTML(document.getElementById('profile'), 15, 15, {
'width': 170
});

doc.save('two-by-four.pdf')
} , 6000);
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue: https://jsfiddle.net/yuriy636/n9LL8ekf/ | Share more details: are you using single file components and webpack? Any error in the console?

Comment: i doesnt pick the styles and other child components. I have added bootstrap sytling but it only takes html basic elements and inline styling

Answer (score 1):

try to use canvas to convert the content of your html page in base 64 before printing the result. this is my own function, printing using canvas

```
printFacture() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF();
    var element = document.getElementById('facture');
    var width= element.style.width;
    var height = element.style.height;
    html2canvas(element).then(canvas => {
        var image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        pdf.addImage(image, 'JPEG', 15, 40, width, height);
        pdf.save('facture' + moment(this.facture.date_debut).format('LL') + '_' + moment(this.facture.date_fin).format('LL') + '.pdf';
    });
}
```

hope it will help you.

Comment: After `'.pdf'` there is a parenthesis missing, it should be `'.pdf');`

Answer (score 1):

```
createPDF () {
    let pdfName = 'mes-enfants'; 
    var doc = new jsPDF();

    doc.fromHTML(document.getElementById('print'), 15, 15, {
      'width': 170
    });

    doc.save(pdfName + '.pdf');
}
```

Comment: I think it can help you

Comment: it's woking well.